# How to Make a Custom Chain Connect Button With Ethers.js

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

I want to make a connect to custom network like that at the bottom of arbiscan.io

How would I do this using ethers.js framework?

Clicking the button should add arbitrum network to user's Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

you should use ethereum library:

```
async function changeNetwork(){
await ethereum.request({ method: 'wallet_addEthereumChain',
   params:[
      {chainId: "IN_HEXADECIMAL_FORM",
      chainName: "CHAIN_NAME",
      nativeCurrency: {
         name: "NATIVE_CURRENCY_NAME",
         symbol: "NATIVE_CURRENCY_SYMBOL",
         decimals: NATIVE_CURRENCY_DECIMALS //In number form
      },
      rpcUrls: ["BLOCKcHAIN_RPC_URL"],
      blockExplorerUrls?: ["BLOCKCHAIN_EXPLORER"]
   ]});
}
```

for more info see [this document](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/rpc-api.html#wallet-addethereumchain)